# Creating a Nested Loop

Tags: java, android, loops

I am trying to create a nested loop which will allow me to display something a particular amount of times, but the problem is that it is only placing one element and not the others. How do I set the coordinates for that?

```
int rows, cols;
rows = 7;
cols = 6;

for (int i=0; i <rows; i++); {
    for (int j=0; j< cols; j++);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because you hardcoded the circle position and it is therefore the same for all circles?

```
canvas.drawCircle(80,  155, 40, white);
```

what about calculating the position?

```
int x = i * radius + 10; // or whatever you wanna calculate here...
int y = j * radius + 10;
canvas.drawCircle(x,  y, 40, white);
```

Comment: Also the inner for loop is immediately closed by a `;` :P

Comment: Beat me! The outer loop is also followed by a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're updating the circle coordinates on each loop cycle! Right now they are hardcoded. This may help:

```
int rows, cols;
rows = 7;
cols = 6;
for (int i=0; i <rows; i++); {
    for (int j=0; j< cols; j++) {
    canvas.drawCircle(80 + (80*i),  155 + (155*j), 40, white);
    }
}
```

I just used the same values for x and y as the offsets, although you may want to play around with them(`80` and `155`) to find the look you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesen't change the position of the circle since you only say to draw it on 80 and 155 
try something like this

```
int rows, cols;
rows = 7; 
cols = 6;
//initial x and y positions
float initialX =80;
float initialY =155;
int radius = 40;
for (int i=0; i <rows; i++); {
     //you need to reset it for each circle
     float drawX = initialX;
    for (int j=0; j< cols; j++){ 
      canvas.drawCircle(initialX,  initialY, radius, white);
      //where 10 will be the little space you want between circles
        drawX+=radius*2+10;
     }
    initialY+=radius*2+10;
}
```